# How to compute the trace distance of a density matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am trying to compute the trace distance of two general $4 \times 4$ density matrices as such:

$D=\frac{1}{2} \, \mathrm{tr} \, |\Delta\rho|_1$ where $\Delta\rho$ is the difference between two density matrices $\rho_1, \rho_2$ and $|A|_1=(A^\dagger A)^{1/2}$. Since density matrices are Hermitian one may write
$|\Delta\rho|_1=(\Delta\rho^2)^{1/2}$ hence one ends up with $D=\frac{1}{2} \, \mathrm{tr} \,|\Delta\rho|_1=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i |\lambda_i|$ where the $|\lambda_i|$ are the eigenvalues of the density matrix $\Delta\rho$.

Is there an efficient manner in which one may calculate this, especially for higher dimensional density matrices?

Comment: Can you show an example of rho1, rho2 and give us an idea of what "higher dimensions" might be?

Comment: @MarcoB: The rho's are any Hermitian matrices which have trace 1. By "higher dimensions"I mean larger density matrices for example of a multilevel or a composite system (they tend to get very messy to calculate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
randomDensityMatrix[n_] := ConjugateTranspose[#2].(#1 #2) &[
  Normalize[RandomReal[{1, 10}, n], Total], 
  RandomVariate[CircularUnitaryMatrixDistribution[n]]
  ]

n = 100;
ρ1 = randomDensityMatrix[n];
ρ2 = randomDensityMatrix[n];
```

Both the following may work:

```
0.5 Re[Tr[MatrixPower[ConjugateTranspose[#].# &[ρ1 - ρ2], 1/2]]]
0.5 Total[Sqrt[Eigenvalues[ConjugateTranspose[#].# &[ρ1 - ρ2]]]]
```

But the second version seems to be ten times faster for n = 100.

**Edit:**

J.M. pointed out in a comment that `Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2` might be a better idea because the condition number of `ConjugateTranspose[ρ1 - ρ2].(ρ1 - ρ2)` might be quite high. I objected that it actually runs *slower* and guessed that would happen because `ρ1 - ρ2` is indefinite. I have to correct this guess: Now I believe that the speed difference might be caused by *Mathematica* not correctly detectling that `ρ1 - ρ2` is Hermitian. The runtimes below somewhat indicate that Apparently, operations like `ConjugateTranspose[#].#&` and `ConjugateTranspose[#] + #&`set some internal flag that makes `Eigenvalue` branch to a special algorithm for Hermitian matrices:

```
n = 100;
RandomSeed[20201229];
ρ1 = randomDensityMatrix[n];
ρ2 = randomDensityMatrix[n];

0.5 Re[Tr[MatrixPower[ConjugateTranspose[#].# &[ρ1 - ρ2], 1/2]]] // RepeatedTiming
0.5 Total[Sqrt[Eigenvalues[ConjugateTranspose[#].# &[ρ1 - ρ2]]]] // RepeatedTiming
Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2 // RepeatedTiming
Total[Abs[SingularValueList[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2 // RepeatedTiming

B = ρ1 - ρ2;
B = 1/2 (ConjugateTranspose[B] + B);

Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[B]]]/2 // RepeatedTiming
Total[Abs[SingularValueList[B]]]/2 // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.013, 0.289995}
>
> {0.00075, 0.289995}
>
> {0.0054, 0.289995}
>
> {0.0014, 0.289995}
>
> {0.00064, 0.289995}
>
> {0.00129, 0.289995}

As you can see, `Eigenvalues` and `SingularValueList` operate much faster on the matrix `B` as on `ρ1 - ρ2`. So

```
Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[ConjugateTranspose[#] + # &[ρ1 - ρ2]]]]/4
```

seems to be the better choice, no matter what the condition number of `ρ1 - ρ2` is.

Comment: Since `ρ1 - ρ2` is Hermitian, `Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2` (equivalently, `Norm[Eigenvalues[ρ1 - ρ2], 1]/2`) should also work, which also avoids the formation of `ConjugateTranspose[matrix].matrix`. (Otherwise, if `ρ1 - ρ2` was not Hermitian, SVD would be necessary.)

Comment: @J.M. Yesss, good point... `ConjugateTranspose[matrix].matrix` may have a much worse condition number than `matrix` itself. But `Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2` seems to branch to a less efficient algorithm for computing the eigenvalues because `ρ1 - ρ2` is indefinite...

Comment: In that case, the choice boils down to whether `ρ1 - ρ2` is well-conditioned (i.e. the ratio of the largest to smallest eigenvalue is not overly large) or not. If it is not badly conditioned, you could get away with forming `ConjugateTranspose[matrix].matrix`.

Comment: Another things that's odd: `Total[Abs[SingularValueList[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2` is actually faster than `Total[Abs[Eigenvalues[ρ1 - ρ2]]]/2`... oO

Comment: @J.M. I think I figured out the reason for the performance degradation and edited my post.

Comment: Nice detective work! ;) Seeing an SVD proceed faster than an eigendecomposition is surely pretty sus (as the kids might say these days) in itself.